# How to open save password popup in react-native android?

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, autofill, textinput, savepassword

I want to open save password popup after successful login in android part using `react-native`.

I have already tried to give `autoComplete` props to username and password TextInput
https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocomplete

```js
    <TextInput
    autoComplete="username"
    importantForAutofill='yes'
    ...
    />
    
    <TextInput
    autoComplete="password"
    importantForAutofill='yes'
    ...
    />
```

It is working fine with `iOS` if i am using `textContentType` props.

Did i missed something in android side setup?

Need to display Google password manager with save password functionality after successful login

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using textContentType prop instead of autoComplete. textContentType is specifically for handling autofill in React Native for both iOS and Android.

Comment: textContentType is only for iOS and i am facing issue in android